# Magento2: Pre-load cache after clean/flush

Tags: magento2, cache

I was wondering if it would be possible to 'preload' the cache after cleaning/flushing it. I know that i.e. 'WP Super Cache' has a function for this in WordPress.

The reason why you want this is that every page loads slowly the first time you open them after cache cleaning. With a preload function, you could make the server read all the pages beforehand, not relying on a visitor to do the first visit.

As far as I know the WP Super Cache plugin calls 5 pages at a time in a loop until it has cached the entire site. Magento would profit from a function like this!

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible.

Try partially disable cache instead fully.

[image: cache management in magento 2]

Comment: Maybe I'll post this as a feature suggest then :)